# Is this something when wrong with Gradle?

Tags: android

I'm building an android app and in my app I've tried to import something. I succeed in working with font awesome and signing in with G account. But when it's come to FireBase I got some problems like this:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/firebase/client/android/AndroidCredentialStore;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Is this the gradle problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tiennguyenhoang.firebaseapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: `defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled = true
 }`

Comment: how can i show code in here?

Comment: post your code (build.gradle)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya now it comes to a new one:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/firebase/tubesock/Base64.class

Comment: i don't know how to post code in here. it's say length is too long

Comment: i know about this problem ,please post your `build.gradle` in your question section .Just edit your question .

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.1' // (v4.5)
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya plz help. Tks so much

Comment: remove `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'`

Comment: Comment one from two 2.5.1 or firebase ui 0.3.1

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya wow it's workkkk. Tks a lot guy :)))) can you explain it for me? I quite don't understand why :D

Answer (score 1):

You are getting

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/firebase/tubesock/Base64.class

Problem for multiple `compile` library.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
}
```

Duplicate entry for above same two library .**Use one** .